# JPA annotation and ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, jpa, constraints, unique-constraint

This question is being asked/mentioned over and over but I could not find if I am doing something wrong or that the problem is "real":
I have an entity class for a simple Oracle table in which there is one field that should be unique.
It has a unique constraint in the DB.
In the entity definition I added the JPA annotation -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "uni_field"))
public class MyTable implements Serializable {
...
@Column(name = "uni_field", unique = true)
@NotNull(message = "Field is required.")
    private String field;
...
```

I am using JBoss 
The problem is that I am always ending up in hibernate exception which tie me up to the JPA implementation if I want to know the constraint violation.
Is there a way to catch a persistency expcetion in such case and provide a user friendly message?
If not than what use is there in the `@Column(name = "uni_field", unique = true)` or `uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "uni_field")` ?

Comment: Define what JPA operation you perform that gives this exception. DataNucleus JPA doesn't throw implementation-specific exceptions ever since it complies with the API (any implementation-specific exception should be nested only)

Comment: I am trying to add an entity using the entity manager. When flushing, assuming the provided 'field' is not unique, the result is a persistent exception with (indeed) a nested hibernate constraint violation exception. But how can I extract the exact constraint violation without creating the dependency on the hibernate jars?

Comment: You can't since JPA doesn't define such semantics, unless there is a low-level SQL exception somewhere that you can do it on (but then that makes you database-dependent)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show "Field is required" message as defined in your annotation, you could catch your exception like this:

```
catch(javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException cve){
  Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> cvs = cve.getConstraintViolations();
  String errMsg = "";
  for (ConstraintViolation<?> cv : cvs) {    
    errMsg = cv.getMessage();
  }
}
```

For reference, please check [OpenJPA Bean Validation Primer](http://openjpa.apache.org/bean-validation-primer.html)